# How to append records from one table to another table in SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas-groupby, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables, first table contains 244 columns with 4945 records, where as in second table 11 columns with 3737 records, but 4 columns are common in both id, name, tocken, tockenold. How to combine this two tables

I tried with UNION but columns must be equal in both .
Tried with full join getting the exact column and record count, but second table records are empty.

Can anyone please help me with this .

Comment: Combine how? Show us some sample table data (simplify, no need for 244 columns,) and the expected combined result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *
  from (
        select id, name, tocken, tockenold
          from table_1
         union 
        select id, name, tocken, tockenold
          from table_2
       ) m
  join table_1 t1
    on m.id = t1.id and m.name = t1.name and m.tocken = t1.tocken and m.tockenold = t1.tockenold 
  join table_2 t2
    on m.id = t2.id and m.name = t2.name and m.tocken = t2.tocken and m.tockenold = t2.tockenold
```

Comment: I have 244 columns in table1 with 4945 records  and only 11 columns in table2 with 3737 records .I tried this, Union is not working in this case . and only 4 columns are common. I need to get 4945+3737 = 8682 records and 251 columns. Common columns records has to append in the first table(table1) but I am getting as empty values in the output table  when I did full join

Comment: as you see in my query, I just do union based on 4 columns. then I join this union with the main tables. So you can get easily any column u want from the tables.

Comment: @Yusuf...Thank you so much for your assistance, It is giving appropriate results with Null columns.

Comment: if it is correct, can u approve as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said:

> I need to get 4945+3737 = 8682 records and 251 columns

Sounds like you just need to do manual union between the two tables:

```
SELECT 
  t1_c1, t1_c2, ..., t1_c240, 
  common_c1, common_c2, common_c3, common_c4,
  null, null, null, null, null, null, null
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  null, null, .... null, -- 240 times
  common_c1, common_c2, common_c3, common_c4,
  t2_c1, t2_c2, ..., t2_c7
FROM table2
```